# Push reference of string element in an array in to new array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, optimization

Given the following code:

```
    var old_Array =["One","Two","..."];
    var len = old_Array .length;
    var new_Array =[];
    for(var i=0;i<len;++i)
    {
      new_Array.push(old_Array [i]); // ----- [1]
    }
```

After line **[1]** `new_Array` is filled with strings.

1. Is Each element actually a reference to string elements in
   `old_Array,` or just copy of each string elements?
2. Does javascript interpreter/compiler optimize line -**[1]** by
   pushing references of each string elements in `old_Array` ?

Comment: Only objects are passed by reference, primitives like strings are copied.

Comment: @PatrickEvans  thank you for the quick reply.but does javascript engine optimize that code line? because the memory allocation for that string object is already there in old_Array .. can we convey the compiler we need that optimization there..rather than having deep copy or shallow copy of each elements

Comment: Think if old_Array has considerable amount of string elements.too many copy operation will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question: Each element is just a copy of each string element of the old array. 
If the array contains object references, the references are copied in the new array. (In this case, the primitive types like strings and numbers are copied by value.)

Answer to the second question: No, the javascript interpreter doesn't optimize line [1] by pushing references of each string elements in old_Array.

A faster and a better approach to copy an array is :

```
var new_Array = old_Array.slice();
```

It clones the old array and returns the reference to the new array.

Comment: thank you.yeah slice() works with the concept of cloning.When you think about cardinality of each two arrays,think you want to have part of old_array elements within new_Array,For representation purpose we could have new_Array structure, If we have 100000 string elements in old array and when we have to only use 5000 of them instead of cloning we create new array structure which fit 5000 with data already exists in old array,therefore instead of do 5000 copy operation we can direct memory location of data vwhich is already exists in old array via reference.

Comment: @Buddhika in that case you have to make sure the old array doesn't get deleted. Also, if the element size is less, copying the element to the new array would make more sense. If the size of array elements is too big, then accessing them via reference would be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.The thing is strings are immutable which means once they are written in the memory they can not be changed. So when you do like

```
var s2 = s.substr(0, 3);
```

`s2` is now a new string but it is not copied to a new memory location, instead represented just as a range in `s`. So as per your question, copying a string from an array of strings shouldn't allocate extra memory for the new string. But then when the array with the original string, is no more needed, the GC should be clever enough to decide what items to remove from and keep in the memory allocated by that array.

I guess the implementations change depending on the JS engine. Here some info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) on this topic.

Comment: Thank you for your concern and answer.

Comment: By the way one thing Redu,as long as s2 won't be changed it can represent as a range of s, but if we assume javascript interpreter/compiler has deep code analysis and run-time checks it can optimize s2 just as range representation of s instead of new String with new memory allocation,but if it detects any modification to s2 will it allocate new memory instead?

Comment: @Buddhika What kind of change can happen to `s2`..? Remember `s2` is also immutable. The only thing that can happen to it is to get deleted by the garbage collector (GC) when there is no more code left referring to it.

Comment: Now got it pal.. your correct ,I missed a point earlier. s2 just C/C++ pointer/reference  like thing. is n't it?